# Retrieving the range/limit of discrete scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to retrieve the range/limit of the x-axis when I plot a discrete variable on it. Specifically, I'm looking at the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

p <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(am = ifelse(am == 0, "Auto", "Manual")) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(factor(am), mpg)) 

p
```

[image: variable am on the x-axis]

There's a lot of space around the "Auto" and "Manual" tick marks. I know that if I inspect the `p` object, the x-axis tick marks are at x = 1 and 2 on a continuous scale, but I would like to know how far the x-axis extends, or what algorithm generates the limits.

```
> layer_scales(p)$x$range
<ggproto object: Class RangeDiscrete, Range, gg>
    range: Auto Manual
    reset: function
    train: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class RangeDiscrete, Range, gg>

> layer_scales(p)$x$range_c
<ggproto object: Class RangeContinuous, Range, gg>
    range: 1 2
    reset: function
    train: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class RangeContinuous, Range, gg>
```

Comment: You can change the amount of space on the x axis before the left-most and after the right-most categories by including the `scale_x_discrete` function in the chart definition with the `expand argument`.  For example, `scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = .2))` will reduce the left and right spaces from the default of .6 to .2.  You'll know what it is because it will either be the default or something you set it to.

Comment: @WaltS Could you point me to where you found the spacing default being .6, thanks!

Comment: @ngc See `?scale_x_discrete`'s `expand` argument: "... The defaults are to expand the scale by 5% on each side for continuous variables, and by 0.6 units on each side for discrete variables."